# Joomla 3 xml files override (e.g. registration.xml)

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am currently working with Joomla 3.

Are changes in (`components/com_users/modules/forms/registration.xml`) secure in case of an update? Or do I have to do it differently? I am a Joomla beginner.

Comment: I don't use Joomla, but out of all of the folders you mention, are they safe from being overwritten during a Joomla update? If not, I would assume Joomla would offer some sort of hooks system so you can add functionality and themes that will survive an update.

Comment: (e.g. WordPress has child themes and plugins, which will be fine across all minor version bumps).

Comment: com_users is usually shipped with Joomla, so I would refrain from altering the files directly. What is it that you want to archieve?

Comment: I would like to add a box to registration . Therefore, I want to change the registration.xml .

Comment: Use  a profile plugin, that is what they exist to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you change this file it will be overwrite.
 Copy you file at path like this to avoid update overwrite.
 `templates/yourtemplate/html/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. unfortunately it is not working . I have copied and pasted the file in( /templates/classyhome3/com_users/modules/forms/registration.xml) Unfortunately it does not overwrite the other file. I did something wrong?

Comment: many thanks again. unfortunately it is not working. the copy is now in ( /templates/classyhome3/html/com_users/modules/forms/registration.xml ) what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I think you have wrong spell modules. It should be models.

Comment: Thanks alot! that's embarrassing. unfortunately it is not the only error . I've corrected ( /templates/classyhome3/html/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml ) . Unfortunately it does not work still . many thanks for your patience

Comment: Ok, maybe you should try with this path: `/templates/classyhome3/html/com_users/registration/registration.xml`.

Comment: do you have an idea please?

Comment: Why are you overriding the module? The module is not a registration form.